# R Plotly changing the color to the bars in the add_bars portion

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

So I have created a Plotly graph in R which has lines for the mean, upper confidence, and lower confidence.  I added the "add_bars" line of code for the count.  This is what I am looking for.  I can change the color of the lines but not the barchart.  This is my code:

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~Date) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~Mean, name = 'Mean', line = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~X95_upper_conf, name = 'Upper Confidence', line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~X95_lower_conf, name = 'Lower Confidence', line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
  add_bars(y = ~Count,name = 'Count', barplot = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')) %>%
    layout(
      margin = list(b = 190, l = 50)) # to fully display the x and y axis labels
```

I have tried adding:

```
barplot = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')
```

and

```
line = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')
```

But neither seems to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use something like `add_bars(..., marker = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')` instead of `barplot = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the color directly in `add_bars`, but you should wrap it in an `I()` expression, to see the color that you entered. Otherwise plotly tries to create a color palette and will use default colors.  And you can also define the color in the `marker` argument of `add_bars`.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Species) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~Sepal.Length) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~Sepal.Width, color = I('red'))


plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Species) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~Sepal.Length) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~Sepal.Width, color = 'blue')

plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Species) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~Sepal.Length) %>%
  add_bars(y = ~Sepal.Width, color = sample(c('yellow','red', 'blue'), 150, T))

plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Species) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~Sepal.Length) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~Sepal.Width, marker = list(color='rgb(0, 0, 0)'))


plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Species) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~Sepal.Length) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~Sepal.Width, marker = list(color="#4286f4"))


plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Species) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~Sepal.Length) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~Sepal.Width, color = rainbow(nrow(iris)))
```